# What statistical test should I use for my data set?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, manova

I have a data set on 20 patients. These patients were administered a cognitive test over the duration of their stay in an inpatient clinic. The cognitive test measured 5 different outcomes (like reaction time, spatial processing etc.) I want to show that the patient's cognition improved over time. I also want to show that the patients cognition improved as they're vitals improved. During my research, I read about the MANOVA test. Would this be the right test to use?

So my dependent variables would be vitals (this is one variable) and the cognitive test results (these are 5 variables). The independent variable would be time.

Comment: Welcome to CV! If you have multiple measurements of the same subjects over time, your data are not independent and (M)ANOVA would be inappropriate. I'm also confused about your research goal: How can the vitals and cognitive test results both be dependent variables if you want to show that one increases as the other does?